# How to create an inline-editable grid in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, gridview

I am new with ASP Dot Net. I am looking for some Data Component for following scenario.

1. User double click on the cell and add some text.
2. Text should automatically save in database.

I have tried with `GridView` but its not working. I am getting `GridView` columns from MSSQL Server Table which are around 600. As mentioned above what I want to do is when a user clicks on a cell it should let the user to add text and then save in database.

Please let me know how to proceed or Should I need to use some other Data Component.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are you using an SQL data source or back-end code? You can check out using a template column for your editable fields so you can run your update on a change event. Here is some info on template columns :
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield.edititemtemplate%28v=vs.100%29.aspx